# Returning any element that isn’t contained in two columns SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, string, hiveql, unnest

I have two columns in a table and I want to create a third column that contains any element that isn’t contained in both columns. For example: the first row of both columns looks like:

```
Col1: [‘apple’,’banana’,’orange’,’pear’]
Col2: [‘apple’,’banana’]
```

And it would return:

```
Col3: [‘orange’, ‘pear’]
```

Essentially the opposite of array_intersect function. I have seen array_diff in php so I am wondering if there is an equivalent function in sql?

Comment: No, the example above is showing the first row of the table. Each row consists of an array and each array has a different number of elements. They are arrays which were formed using “collect_set” function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

explode col1 and use array_contains+case statement, assemble array again using collect_set or collect_list.

Demo:

```
with your_data as (--Test data. Use your table instead of this
select stack(1,
array('apple','banana','orange','pear'),
array('apple','banana')
) as (col1, col2)
)

select col1, col2, 
       collect_set(case when array_contains(t.col2, e.col1_elem) then null else e.col1_elem end) as col3
  from your_data t
       lateral view explode(t.col1) e as col1_elem
group by col1,  col2
```

Result:

```
col1                                 col2                col3
["apple","banana","orange","pear"]  ["apple","banana"]  ["orange","pear"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a primary key, then I think this will do what you want:

```
select t.pk, collect_set(case when c2.el is null then c1.el end)
from (t lateral view
      explode(t.col1) c1 as el 
     ) left join
     (t t2 lateral view
      explode(t2.col2) c2 as el
     )
     on t.pk = t2.pk and
        c1.el = c2.el
group by t.pk;
```